# product description not displayed properly on magento

Tags: css, magento

I'm having trouble fixing the product description display on my magento store. It displays just fine with chrome. However, it is coming on top of the product details in firefox. Have a look: http://www.chefmaha.com/index.php/default/dessert/cream-filled-basboosah.html

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="clearer"></div>
```

Or add a `.clear` rule to your CSS.

Comment: @clockworkgeek...However, now the "quick overview" section as well as the "add to compare" link are not displayed properly: http://www.chefmaha.com/index.php/default/dessert/cream-filled-basboosah.html... any idea y?

Comment: You can see the `add-to-cart-box` fieldset has a `float: left` in it's CSS. Anything that exists after it must then appear on it's right, unless you put another clearer element immediately after. So the answer is to add a clearer element or unset the float for `.add-to-cart-box`.